# How change React Native and Metro Bundler port

Tags: android, react-native, bundler

I'm trying to start the React Native debugger and bundler in port `8088` because `8081` used by another program, using the following command:

```
react-native run-android --port=8088
```

The emulator reverse is set correctly

> Running C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8088 tcp:8088

But metro bundler is starting in port 8081

[image: metro bundler console]

Which would be the best way to start it once some program is reading my 8081 port and I can't stop it.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to get my RN app running on port **8088** instead of default port **8081**. I've spend almost 2 days to figure out how to do this, but the solutions found were not working in my case. Finally i've found a way to tackle this problem. Follow the 3 steps and get this resolved.

1. In `metro.config.js` file, add the following snippet within the `module.exports`.

> server: {
>       port: 8088,   }

2. Search for 8081 in the entire ios project and replace the value with `8088`. I had to do this in the following files for the variable `RCT_METRO_PORT`.

> - ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core/React/RCTDefines.h
> - ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTDefines.h

3. Run the build as usual, this time with the port passed as an argument.

> `npx react-native run-ios --port 8088`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two files needed to be modified about port 8081:

1.react-native/local-cli/server/server.js - default

2.react-native/React/React.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj - replace all the  8081 ports with your desired ports in  above two files

Your port will be changed.

Comment: This gets overridden on pod install

Answer (score 2):

After migrating the React Native CLI configs into `@react-native-community/cli` changing the default PORT for metro bundler became very easier, for changing the default PORT just export an environment variable by the following command inside you project path:

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT=8590
```

Also, find the `RCTDefines.h` files inside your `ios/Pods` folder, there are two of them and inside both of them change the value `8081` to `8590`.

For a test run the `echo $RCT_METRO_PORT` and if you see the new PORT `8590`, it is changed now and easily run your project with default commands.

***NOTE***: For using React Native Debugger for development just press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then change the port value `8081` to `8590`.

Comment: The pods folder is cleared on each pod install

Answer (score -1):

You need to overwrite the `RCT_METRO_PORT` macro variable to ensure your app points to the correct port when running via xcode or `react-native run-ios`. This can be done by opening the Pods project within your workspace, navigating to Build Settings and adding a Preprocessor Macro. For example `RCT_METRO_PORT=7777`, if the port you are using is `7777`.

[image]